# Stored proc Always Encrypted and CASE with default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, encryption, always-encrypted

I am testing always encrypted to be potentially used in a legacy application.  For a test I encrypted an NVARCHAR column in one of the basic lookup tables in the application.  I got warnings from the encryption wizard warning me about some of the stored procedures not measuring up.
Upon inspection of the procedure,  I noticed it is complaining about a particular CASE statement on the encrypted column.(NOTE: the encrypted column is **adl.adl_Text NVARCHAR(50)** ).  The column returns a default(pre defined string) in the case that the table PK is null.  I understand an ISNULL may work here but this is an example of the problem.
There is no string comparison going on with the encrypted column so I am a bit confused what the issue is.

I have tried using a constant at the top of the procedure instead of the literal string inline with the query.

```
DECLARE @add_removed NVARCHAR(50)
SET @add_removed = 'Address Removed'

SELECT addr.Field1
  , addr.Field2
  , CASE WHEN addr.FieldPK IS NULL THEN @add_removed ELSE adl.adl_Text END AS StatusReason
FROM address addr
LEFT JOIN Address_Delete_Reason adl ON adl.PK = addr.adl_FK
```

I previously had:

```
SELECT addr.Field1
  , addr.Field2
  , CASE WHEN addr.FieldPK IS NULL THEN 'Address Removed' ELSE adl.adl_Text END AS StatusReason
FROM address addr
LEFT JOIN Address_Delete_Reason adl ON adl.PK = addr.adl_FK
```

The error I am getting is :

```
Error: Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with nvarchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBTEST').
```

Comment: the problem is that the column is returned to the client to be decrypted there. so it cant potentially have a mix of some encrypted values and some plain text values.

Comment: I am wondering how to go about refactoring a legacy application that uses these types of stored procedures. Do you have to add extra parameters to the offending stored procs?  Will the driver know it has to encrypt that parameter even though it is not used to compare to an encrypted column?

Comment: Passing these values as parameters to the SP is an option. Another is to write them in a table in the database, encrypt the text column the same way, and when you need a value, read it from this helper table.

Answer (score 1):

Since the procedure existed before applying the encryption, try refreshing the always encrypted metadata for the stored proc using [sp_refresh_parameter_encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refresh-parameter-encryption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> The encryption metadata for parameters of a module can become
>   outdated, if:
>
> Encryption properties of a column in a table the module references,
>   have been updated. For example, a column has been dropped and a new
>   column with the same name, but a different encryption type, encryption
>   key or an encryption algorithm has been added.

You'll probably need to do this for every proc that references the newly encrypted objects:

```
EXEC sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption @name = '[YourSchema].[YourProc]'
```